# Crashes when printing a specific string in array swift xcode

Tags: ios, swift

The app crashes when I try to print a string from an array. So if I type pie in the text field the output should be:

> /summon fallingsand ~ ~ ~ {Command:"pie"}

but the app crashes instead. Any help?

Code:

```
@IBAction func GenerateClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    OutputView.hidden = false;
    myTextView.endEditing(true)
    let fullName: String = myTextView.text;
    let fullNameArr = fullName.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    var c = 0
    let i = fullNameArr.count - 1
    while c <= i {
        c = i + 1
        OutputView.text = "/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {block:\"minecraft:command_block\",Command:\""
        OutputView.text = OutputView.text + fullNameArr[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's most likely a "out of bounds" error. Isn't it supposed to be `fullNameArr[c]` and `c++` (not the language) rather than `c = i + 1` and that `c++` after the `OutputView.text` lines?

Comment: `c = i + 1` is okay since he is doing `fullNameArr[1]`

Comment: Indeed it's okay but then the while loop is meaningless because the body is executed always once @Breek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vadian said it looks like  a `index out of bounds` error when you try to `fullNameArr[1]` but `fullNameArr` might only contain one or no element

So you should check before append to your string:

```
    OutputView.text = "/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {block:\"minecraft:command_block\",Command:\""
    if i >= 2 {
        OutputView.text = OutputView.text + fullNameArr[1];
    }
```